# Do I need to call DeleteObject on CFont

Tags: mfc

I was wondering, do I need to call DeleteObject in the following case?

```
CFont* oldFont = label.GetFont();
LOGFONT oldLogFont;
oldFont->GetLogFont(&oldLogFont);
oldLogFont.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
CFont newFont;
newFont.CreateFontIndirectW(&oldLogFont);
label.SetFont(&newFont, true);
// Do I need to call oldFont->DeleteObject() or newFont->DeleteObject()?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you don't.  MFC classes are [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) classes. When the object drops out of scope (ie gets deconstructed) the object will be deleted appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, is there any MSDN reference for this? I can't find one, though there must be.